# SSL Renegotiation failures - Impact?

Tags: ssl, tls1.2

This is a very generic question and I hope I can get it right.

I am looking into SSL/TLS renegotiations and have read up a bit on it. Here's what I've understood from my reading:

Clients are grouped into two main groups from the standpoint of SSL/TLS renegotiations, patched and unpatched. This refers to if they're vulnerable to an Man In the Middle attack (CVE-2009-3555?) or not.

A renegotiation made with a patched client is called a "Secure renegotiation" while a renegotiation made with a unpatched client is called an "Insecure renegotiation".

The articles I have read has used a Web shop as an example where a user browsers the shop without being logged in. When the user decides to log in his/her client could then use renegotiation to login and save some time/resources.

What I don't understand from that example is why the browser would have to re-establish the SSL/TLS session when it already has one to the site? Unless the login is made over another domain, in which case I would have assumed that it would be a completely new session since the client can't assume that the same web server would handle that domain.

Most resources is very vague and I would like to understand from a practical standpoint:

- In what scenario are they used?
- What is the benefit?
- What is the behavior of a client if they fail or are rejected?

Any answers/theories/suggestions would be appreciated.

/Patrik

Answer (score 1):

They are used when either side wants to change the protocol or the cipher suite, or if the server now wants to request a client certificate and didn't before.

Comment: Agreed. But when would the client want to change protocol or cipher suite?

Client certificate was a good suggestion!